# Making windows have better names

Tags: windows-10, matlab

When I'm programming in Matlab, the scripts that I write all have the directory as part of their name, resulting in it being impossible for me to distinguish them by their names. Here's a picture to see what I mean.

[image: picture]

Any ideas on how I can make it easier to see what I'm looking at?

Comment: then you have to ask Matlab developers to give an option to show a different title, or put files in a better path

Comment: The title of a window is defined by the application registering it, in this case Matlab. Thus, the only way for what you want to be accomplished is to ask Matlab developers to change their window management code to, for example, show only the filename in the titlebar.

Comment: Does the post [Dynamically changing the command window title in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466348/dynamically-changing-the-command-window-title-in-matlab) relate to your problem? Another possibility is [Setting window/picture title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990951/setting-window-picture-title).

Comment: I should put up an answer in this case, but which one worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities for changing the title of a Matlab window.

**Change the title of the command window**

This is done by the following script ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466348/dynamically-changing-the-command-window-title-in-matlab)) :

```
function idetitle(Title)
%IDETITLE Set Window title of the Matlab IDE
%
% Examples:
% idetitle('Matlab - Foo model')
% idetitle(sprintf('Matlab - some big model - #%d', feature('getpid')))

    win = appwin();
    if ~isempty(win)
        win.setTitle(Title);
    end
end
```

**Change the Name-property of the figure window**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990951/setting-window-picture-title) :

> ```
> img = imread('pic.jpg','jpg');
> r = img(:,:,1);
> g = img(:,:,2);
> b = img(:,:,3);
>
> figure('Name','this is the red channel'), imshow(r);
> figure('Name','this is the green channel','NumberTitle','off'), imshow(g);
> title(gca,'you can also place a title like this')    
>
> fh = figure; imshow(b);
> set(fh,'Name','this is the blue channel')
> ```
>
> Also, if you call `imshow(g,[])`, it will auto-scale the image to
>   min/max.